# Why I am getting Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 60

Tags: php, ssl, curl, laravel-5

I am doing project in laravel. I am using plivo api for sending sms. For that I followed all the steps mentioned at

https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/send-a-single-sms/ .

but When I tried to run my php file then I am getting error message as

> "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' in G:\Xampp\htdocs\plivoTrial\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:187 Stack trace: #0 G:\Xampp\htdocs\plivoTrial\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(150): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array) #1 G:\Xampp\htdocs\plivoTrial\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(103): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) #2 G:\Xampp\htdocs\plivoTrial\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) #3 G:\Xampp\htdocs\plivoTria in G:\Xampp\htdocs\plivoTrial\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 187".

My php file looks like,

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Plivo\RestAPI;

$auth_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$auth_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$p = new RestAPI($auth_id, $auth_token);

// Set message parameters
$params = array(
'src' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx', 
'dst' => '91xxxxxxxxxx', 
'text' => 'Hi, I am Amarja :)', 
'url' => 'http://localhost/untitled/sentsms.php', 
'method' => 'POST' 
);
// Send message
$response = $p->send_message($params);

echo "Response : ";
print_r ($response['response']);

echo "<br> Api ID : {$response['response']['api_id']} <br>";

echo "Message UUID : {$response['response']['message_uuid'][0]} <br>";

?>
```

I am not getting how to solve this problem. please help and many thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats hard to understand about: self signed certificate in certificate chain (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html ?

Comment: Actually I did same project before. This new project is at a place where the old one is. That old project runs perfectly, thats why I am not getting what the issue is....I think problem might be related to the composer

Comment: try it with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` in your core file

Comment: I tried this in Plivo's plivo.php file but still it shows same error.

Comment: Is it possible to use auth id and auth token in more than one project?

Answer (score 11):

**Do not disable SSL**

Instead, **fix your PHP installation**.

[These directions](https://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/) worked for me on Windows.

This problem shows up when your CA root certificates are missing or out-of-date. Since at the moment **ALL** the Windows platform PHP installers **DO NOT** include the CA root certificates in the distribution, its much more common on Windows than on Linux.

Here is how you update the CA root certificates:

1. [Download](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) an up-to-date copy of CA root certificates.
2. Save the file "cacert.pem" to your computer. For example **c:\xampp\php**
3. Add the location of the "cacert.pem" file from **Step 2** to your **php.ini** file.
   Search for `[curl]` in your **php.ini** file and update or add the following line:
   `curl.cainfo=c:\xampp\php\cacert.pem`
4. Restart your web server.

Curl now has a valid CA root certificate bundle and can verify the SSL certificates of remote servers.

If you are running any of the [Google Cloud Platform PHP examples](https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore) on a Windows computer you'll get the following cURL error : [**CURLE_SSL_CACERT (60)**](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html#CURLESSLCACERT) - Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates. That error should now be self-explanatory along with how to fix it.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this process? I found the php extension "certainty" does this, but requires a current;y valid cacert.pem to run. 

What cna be done to keep these up-to-date?