# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'HTTP Error (60)

Tags: php, curl, xampp

Hi I am getting this error when running an application on XAMPP on MAC OS Sierra 10.2

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'HTTP Error (60): SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain'`

Not sure if anything to do with this `openssl.cafile=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt`

I have no idea what to do?

Cheers

Comment: This is not OS specific but rather a curl problem in php. Have a look at this link http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Thanks everyone for the input. I ended up reinstalling XAMPP and this solved this cert issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access some resource over https and the remote server is showing an untrusted certificate.

- It might just mean your installation is outdated, you can follow the instructions on this anwser https://stackoverflow.com/a/41274288/3474436.
- If you're on a dev environment you could disable these checks with these two settings :

  ```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  ```

  But do that at your own risk, as it won't prevent any [MitM attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). Therefore you may instead add the certificate into the keystore if you're sure you can trust it.
- If the remote server you're trying to access belongs to you, you should obtain a certificate, for instance https://letsencrypt.org/ provides free trusted certificates.